# Web calling application using SIP Servlet

Tags: spring-mvc, sip-servlet

I am new to SIP Servlet. I want to build a web calling application.

After googling for hours I got to know about SIP Servlet which fits my requirement. SIP is quite similar to HTTP. However, I have few doubts listed below. It will be really helpful if anyone could help me here -

1 > I am not able to figure out how the SIP servlet methods will be invoked. Lets say I have a web page which has a button called " Call Mr. Xyz". Once the user clicks this button which will trigger a voice call over web to Mr. Xyz. Also, I have a controller mapped to this request and upon clicking this button, a call goes to a controller( I am using Spring MVC). Do I need to invoke the SIP servlet methods from this controller or can I directly call SIP method from JSP ( Like AJAX call ) ?

2 > Also, I am not sure how the voice call(voice conversation) will be happening after the connection has been established.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What are you requirements ?

I would suggest looking at [Restcomm Connect](https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect) instead of SIP Servlets.

SIP Servlets is low level while RestComm-Connect lets you use a REST API to create the call without having to know all the details of the SIP and Media protocols. Restcomm-Connect is actually built on top of [Restcomm SIP Servlets](https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets) but it's allowing Web Developers to focus on their business logic rather than understanding the complexity of Telecom protocols.